# Proc Transpose 2 columns together in SAS

Tags: sas, transpose

I have a dataset like this:

```
  ID       Visit_No   Sequence_no     Event_code        Notes
  1             11             1            44           boo foo bar
  1             11             2            52           bat-man 
  2             21             1             44          banjo banjo
  2             21             2             32          foo bar
  2             25             1            99           aba
```

WHERE ID is a unique identifier  for a person at a visit and sequence No is to be my new field name as such

```
  ID          Visit_NO      EVENT_1     NOTE_1    EVENT2     NOTE_2      
  1              11            44     boo foo bar   52      bat-man           
  2              21            44     banjo banjo   32      foo bar
  2              25            99        aba
```

I have code as such

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA = data out = transposed_data
PREFIX = EVENT_ ;
BY ID Visit_No;
id SEQUENCE_NO ;
var event_code Notes ; 
run;
```

I don't know how to say 2 prefixes because right now it just has the notes UNDER the event code like

```
  ID          Visit_NO      EVENT_1             EVENT2    
   1             11           44                   52
   1             11          boo foo bar        bat-man
```

.... etc

I expect this but I can't figure out how to say 2 prefixes. I don't want to mix up which event code goes with each note because each one is unique and in my real dataset is important to understand the data.  Is there a way I can transpose them together?

Comment: Transpose separately and merge by ID or use the method/macro presented here: http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/A_Better_Way_to_Flip_(Transpose)_a_SAS_Dataset

Comment: I transposed separately for now but I will study the macro. thank you

Comment: I highly recommend the macro, quite quick and useful, especially for getting the order of your columns the way you want.

Comment: I also added another answer to the duplicate question using a data step.